# Android volley adapter notification

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm new in using Volley in android and work with REST. In my application i need to have three main page :

1. `splashActivity`
2. `menuActivity`
3. `newslistActivity`.

I need to fetch data in `JSON` type from web-service and show the number of Total new news in menu activity and after click on news menu go to `newslistActivity`.

I do not know what strategy is best to use volley for cache and networking stuff.should i first load data in `splashActivity` and then in `menuActivity` again?

I read this [sample](https://github.com/angtwr31/fblikenewsfeedusingvolley) to use volley .In this sample first activity is the activity contain `listview` and it easily call `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in this activity but my application is different.  I do not know  if i load all news list in `splashActivity` when should i call `listAdapter`'s `notifyDataSetChanged`?

Comment: If your splash activity doesn't contain anything that you are loading data into, then you shouldn't call Volley in that Activity's code

Comment: @cricket_007 I saw a lot of sample of new application where it seems the application fetch all data from server in splashActivity. how do the work?

Comment: @serenei if you are not showing the next activity until the data is loaded thenyou can load the data in splash activity and pass that data (may be json or a serializable object) in bundle to the next activity and use it to populate fields or lists accordingly

Comment: They probably just do `startActivity` inside the `onResponse` of the Volley call.

Comment: @cricket_007 no they won't.they loaded data in `splashactivity` with `AsyncTask` and ave the data in text file then in next activity they check the existence of file .if the file exists, they load data from file . Is mentioned strategy good with volley or is there any better strategy?

Comment: Why are you mentioning AsyncTask?? I thought you wanted Volley? Also, volley doesn't use text files... Just do what jay mentioned above